# SQLite constraint violation - How to insert data to this schema?

Tags: insert, sqlite

First of all, sorry for the question but I was hours searching for a solution and the only things that I got are Java exceptions. I'm developing a little web crawler for movies, so I created this two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies(
    movie_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    info VARCHAR(250)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genres(
    genre_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);
```

Well, as you can see is a many to many relationship, so I made a junction table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies_genres(
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    genre_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(movie_id, genre_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(movie_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genres(genre_id)
);
```

And I'm trying to insert data with (**arg** are the method arguments):

```
INSERT INTO movies_genres(movie_id, genre_id) 
SELECT m.movie_id, g.genre_id FROM
SELECT (movie_id FROM movies WHERE title = arg) AS m
CROSS JOIN SELECT (genre_id FROM genres WHERE title = arg) AS g;
```

But I get this **SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed**. I don't know where is the error, maybe is in the schema but I can't see the error. Any idea on how fix it?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do you have any data in movies_genres?

```
SELECT * FROM movies_genres;
```

If not, you can check if the primary key is missing in any of the sources tables

```
SELECT movie_id FROM movies GROUP BY movie_id HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

and the same for genres. If above is ok, the error should not happen, but you can check with:

```
SELECT m.movie_id, g.genre_id 
FROM ( -- I assume the parentheses was a typo and moved it
    SELECT movie_id 
    FROM movies 
    WHERE title = arg1
) AS m
CROSS JOIN ( -- see comment above
    SELECT genre_id 
    FROM genres WHERE title = arg2
) AS g
GROUP BY m.movie_id, g.genre_id 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

You can btw simplify your query to:

```
SELECT m.movie_id, g.genre_id 
FROM movies m
JOIN genres g
    ON m.title = arg1  
   AND g.title = arg2
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late feedback but I was so focused on the problem that I forgot it. I seem the issue with the second statement. Btw I simplify my insert statement, thank you so much!